# Non English UTF 8 characters changes when posted from HTML Form

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, character-encoding

When I post non english characters from my HTML Form, on server side I recieve some UTF-8 character, but not the original UTF-8 character. For example, in Kannada '**ಇಲಾಖೆಯ**' becomes '**à²‡à²²à²¾à²–à³†à²¯**', or in french, '**département**' becomes '**dÃ©partement**'.

My HTML Form has attribute `accept-charset` as `UTF-8`, I have `meta content type` to `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. My JBoss server is also configured for `UTF-8`.

I have compiled source code as UTF-8 in Maven.
I have added CharactersetEncoderFilter in web.xml as -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is there anyway to get back the original text that was posted from the HTML Form ?

Comment: What diagnosis have you performed? What does your code look like? What does the HTTP request from the browser look like? (Ideally including the bytes.) How are you observing the broken strings? There's not really enough information here to help you at the moment.

Comment: What you describe happens when UTF-8 binary data is processed in another charset, such as ISO-8859-1. So you have a charset mismatch somewhere between the browser and the script that is receiving the data.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your JSPs have pageEncoding=UTF-8. In web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Is your browser Internet Exploder?

Is the input actually UTF-8 or is it copy-pasted from MS Word?

Comment: Windows clipboard maintains a UTF-16 version and native character encoding of any string copied to it. Assuming the OP's browser is half decent, they'll have no problem coping non-ASCII chars from Word via the clipboard.